# How to set trigger ID from shortcut to enable modal on slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

Need a slack interactive dialog box, for that I have:

1. A shortcut created with a callback ID.
2. A modal created in a payload.

How can I enable a modal using a shortcut? 
In API, they mention that it can be done using trigger ID.
But I am not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1st get trigger id from the request and use it in your modal view.

 function doPost(e) {
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined'){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length;
      
    var params = e.parameter;
    var token = e.token;
    var command = params.command;
     var tokenOurs = "xoxb-44xxxxxxxx731-xxxxxxxxxx177-bxxxxxxxxxxxxY";
    var trigger_id = params.trigger_id;
     var chanel = e.channel;
    var slackUrl = "https://slack.com/api/views.open";
    
    var callbackId = params.callback_id;
      
      
      
      // extract the relevant data
       var parameter = e.parameter;
     
      
    if (command == "/powerrangers"){
    
    
    var dialog = {
    "token": tokenOurs,
    "trigger_id": trigger_id,
      "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
      view: {
         }
    }
    
    var options = {
    method : 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
    Authorization : 'Bearer ' + tokenOurs},
    payload : JSON.stringify(dialog)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackUrl, options);
    }
```